# How to declare a subtype with a the whole negative range of Integer type in Ada?

Tags: types, ada

If I'd like to declare a positive only Integer type, all I need to do is this:

```
      subtype Positive is Integer range 0..Integer'Last;
```

I figured I could apply the same logic to declare a negative type like this:

```
      subtype Negative is Integer range Integer'First..1;
```

Yet, while compiling I get this error:

```
    attribute "First" may not be used in a subtype mark
```

Why do I get this error, and how can I declare a negative only subtype?

Comment: Your `Negative` subtype includes two non-negative values.

Comment: Shouldn't `Integer'First` give me the lowest value of the `Integer` type?

Comment: Yes, but your subtype includes the values `0` and `1`. If you want only negative values, you need `Integer'First .. -1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is probably due to a typo somewhere, because your exact example is fine:

```
package SO is
   subtype Negative is Integer range Integer'First..1;
end SO;
```

Compiling:

```
% gnatmake so.ads
gcc-4.9 -c -gnata -gnato -fstack-check -gnat12 -gnatyO -gnatv -gnati1 -gnatf -gnatn so.ads

GNAT 4.9.2
Copyright 1992-2014, Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Compiling: so.ads (source file time stamp: 2016-08-19 05:05:16)
 3 lines: No errors
%
```

Comment: Found the error, forgot to mention `range` in the code. Thank you.

Comment: Edward, if you had posted your actual code in the first place you would have got an answer even more quickly.